# Simple Java Timer program error

Tags: java, timer, reset

Hi i have been trying to do a java program timer that resets every time once the user key in a number. i have tried creating two methods and stop the other but no avail . please post any other possible solutions

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while(true)
        {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=reader.nextInt();

        if(a == 1)
            {
            Timer timer = new Timer("Printer");
            MyTask t = new MyTask();
            timer.schedule(t, 0, 1000);
            }
        else
            {
            Timer timer = new Timer("Printer");
            MyTask t = new MyTask();
            timer.schedule(t, 0, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    //times member represent calling times.
    private int times = 0;


    public void run() {
        times++;
        if (times <= 5) {
             System.out.println(""+times);
        } else {
            timer.cancel();
            update();
            //Stop Timer.


        }

    }

    private void update() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Updated timer");

                }
            };
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000);
        }

}
```

Updated

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true)
        {

        int a=reader.nextInt();

            Timer timer = new Timer("Printer");
            MyTask t = new MyTask();
            timer.schedule(t, 0, 1000);
        }
    }
}

class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    //times member represent calling times.
    private int times = 0;


    public void run() {
        times++;
        if (times <= 5) {
             System.out.println(""+times);
        } else {
            this.cancel();
            //Stop Timer.


        }

    }
}
```

Update its working anything needs to be improve ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main {

    public static Timer timer ; 
    public static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true)
        {

        int a=reader.nextInt();
                count++;
            stop();
        }
    }

    public static void stop()
    {

        if(count == 1 )
        {
            timer = new Timer("Printer");
            MyTask t = new MyTask();
            timer.schedule(t, 0, 1000);
        }
        else
        {   
            timer.cancel();
            timer = new Timer("Printer");
            MyTask t = new MyTask();
            timer.schedule(t, 0, 1000);
        }
    }

}

class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    //times member represent calling times.
    private int times = 0;


    public void run() {
        times++;
        if (times <= 5) {
             System.out.println(""+times);
        } else {
            this.cancel();
            //Stop Timer.


        }

    }
```

}

Comment: The code for if(a == 1) statement is the same for true and false conditions, so the "if" doesn't not make sense, always will be executed the same code...

Answer (score 1):

You've lots of problems with that code including:

- You're creating a new Scanner object with each iteration of your while loop -- don't do that. Create the object once *before* the loop.
- You're continually creating new Timers and TimerTasks, with the implicit assumption that each new one will somehow change the previous one, and this simply won't happen.
- Your if/else clause is unnecessary since both code blocks are identical.
- You create all Timers and TimerTasks locally with limited scope, preventing code elsewhere in your class from being able to access it and attempt to change its state.
- You're asking a somewhat ambiguous question
- And are asking others to provide code for you, something we don't do for homework assignments.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers i read and used them. My initial idea was not asking for direct answer but ask for pointers where u gave thanks mate!